# mapping custom xml to java using jaxb includes inheritence and hashmap

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have xml like

```
<Data>
<Protocol1
    var1="aaa"
    var2="bbb"
/>
<Protocol2
    var3="vv"
    var4="ff"
/>
</Data>
```

We have classes like Protocol1,Protocol2..etc derived from base class Protocol. like

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Protocol1")
class Protocol1 extends Protocol
{
    @XmlAttribute
    String var1;

    @XmlAttribute
    String var2;
}
class Protocol
{
}
```

Class Data can have List or Map of protocols. For map key will be like "Protocol1" and value will be object of Protocol1 class.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Data")
class Data
{
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MapAdapter.class)
   Map<String,Protocol> protocolMap;
}
```

I tried doing like http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/06/moxys-xmlvariablenode-using-maps-key-as.html but was not successful. 
How to use variable node and inheritance together for un-marshalling.  Please guide.
Current code is :

```
//Adapter
public class MapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<List<ProtocolBase>,Map<String,ProtocolBase>>{
    @Override
    public List<ProtocolBase> marshal(Map<String,ProtocolBase> map){
        return new ArrayList<ProtocolBase>(map.values());
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String,ProtocolBase> unmarshal(List<ProtocolBase> lst){
        Map<String,ProtocolBase> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(ProtocolBase p : lst){
            map.put(p.getClass().getSimpleName(),p);
        }
        return map;
    }
}
//Base Class
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({ArrayList.class,Protocol1.class})
public class ProtocolBase {

    public ProtocolBase() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
//Derived class
@JsonRootName( "Protocol1")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Protocol1 extends ProtocolBase{

    @XmlAttribute(name="Name")
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String _name;
}
@JsonRootName( "Protocol2")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Protocol2 extends ProtocolBase{

    @XmlAttribute(name="Name")
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String _name;
}


//Main class
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Data")
@JsonRootName("Data")
@XmlSeeAlso({ArrayList.class,Protocol1.class,ProtocolBase.class})
public class Data {

   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MapAdapter.class)
    @XmlElements({
           @XmlElement(name="Protocol1",type=Protocol1.class)
       })
    private Map<String,ProtocolBase> protocolList = new HashMap<String, ProtocolBase>();

}

// Usage
device = new Data();
Protocol1 p1 = new Protocol1();
p1.set_name("ADT");


Protocol2 p2 = new Protocol2();
p2.set_name("ADT1");



device.getProtocolList().put("Protocol1",(SSDeviceProtocol) p1);
device.getProtocolList().put("Protocol2",(SSDeviceProtocol) p2);

JAXBContext jc = (JAXBContext) JAXBContext.newInstance();
Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
m.marshal(device, System.out);

//Expected output
<Data>
<Protocol1 Name="ADT"/> 
<Protocol2 Name="ADT1"/>    
</Data>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two solutions to your problem, depending on your JAXB Implementation :

> 1. Using the Reference JAXB Implementation

With the reference implementation, you can do this :

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Data")
class Data
{
   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MapAdapter.class)
   @XmlElements({
       @XmlElement(name="Protocol1",type=Protocol1.class),
       @XmlElement(name="Protocol2",type=Protocol2.class),
       ....
   })
   Map<String,Protocol> protocolMap;
}
```

Your adapter should extends `XmlAdapter<List<Protocol>,Map<String,Protocol>>` :

```
public class MapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<List<Protocol>,Map<String,Protocol>>{
    @Override
    public List<Protocol> marshal(Map<String,Protocol> map){
        return new ArrayList<Protocol>(map.values());
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String,Protocol> unmarshal(List<Protocol> lst){
        Map<String,Protocol> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(Protocol p : lst){
            map.put(p.getClass().getSimpleName(),p);
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

The problem with this solution is that you have to list every extended class in the `@XmlElements` annotation.

> 2. Using EclipseLink MoXY JAXB Implementation

Blaise Doughan's example uses a custom JAXB implementation, if you are willing to  use it, you can use the following solution :

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Data")
class Data
{
   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MapAdapter.class)
   @XmlPath(".")
   Map<String,Protocol> protocolMap;
}
```

Beware though, a quick search on the subject lead to a currently [open bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=457169) when you use `@XmlPath(".")` and `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` conjointly.

Also, you should use `@XmlAccessorType` on your 'Protocol' classes instead of `@XmlRootElement`, that should be reserved to object that represent a root XML element.

Comment: It would be great if you could give adapter example

Comment: @AdtG Adapter added and answer edited, as supertypes cannot specify wildcard.

Comment: Thank you @Dimpre . Now atleast data is getting mapped. but attributes under protocol are missing. like <Data> <Protocol1 /><Data>.

Comment: @AdtG Add accessors or `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` to your `Protocol` classes. If it doesn't work, try adding `@XmlSeeAlso({Protocol1.class,Protocol2.class, ...})` to your `Data`class but it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: no success, Still the output is same. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Data>
    <Protocol1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="arrayList"/>
</Data>

Comment: It will be great help if you could post adapter for MoXY JAXB Implementation. I need to try that way also.

Comment: You can use the same adapter for MoXY. Could you get in debug and look what the list look like in the `unmarshal` method of your adapter ?

Comment: It is not going to unmarshal method.I had put breakpoint there, nut surprisingly control not going to unmarshal method.

Comment: Could you update the code in your question to reflect what you currently use now ?

Comment: I do not have time to properly edit my answer so i'll do it later, but if i remember correctly, jackson understand the basic jaxb annotation, so you should remove jackson annotations. Also, if you have duplicate protocol with the same name, use Lists instead of Maps and remove the adapter and see if it works.

Comment: Duplicate protocol will not be there..Let me correct it..I will try removing jackson aanotations